# Android Studio design tab not showing the whole application

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio and I'm making a simple form as my first project.

The body of my form is in a ScrollView and it works when run on an actual device (I can see all views and layouts added) but the design tab of Android Studio won't scroll past the device dimensions to show the entire application. How can I edit it to make that possible so I can keep building the form in the design tab?

[Android Studio Design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0hZ6.png)

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0):

For the layout design, which device did you choose? You can change the mode to the device that you are testing.This way it will show up exactly on your device the way you designed in the layout.

[(See the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsRrS.png)

Comment: I just left it to be Nexus 4 as I did not know the dimensions for a Galaxy Tab. Even if the dimensions are wrong, if you can scroll on the actual device, shouldn't you be able to scroll on the editor too?

Comment: I don't think you can scroll on the layout, because it's just a design. What I do is create an activity, assign the activity with the layout. Only run this activity. Once everything looks good to me, I implementing to the real activity that I want.

Comment: Oh that's not a bad idea. Thank you!